# How can I typecast an NSArray element to double?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

An other way please.
I have an array whole elements are doubles. How can I get the content out as double?e.g.

```
coordinate.latitude = [coords objectAtIndex:0];// value inside it is 61.2180556;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store primitive doubles in NSArray. You have either stored them as NSNumber or NSString. In either case use:

```
coordinate.latitude = [[coords objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
```

Comment: True they are Strings. Thanks.